# amateur radio proposal on SE

Tags: discussion

There's a [HAM radio proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43029/amateur-radio) going on.  Licensed HAMs tend to be qualified and enlightened people.  We need them HAMs here on EE.SE .  If HAM questions require some special policy, let's define it.

P.S.
The question "[Where are the HAMs?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338/where-are-the-hams)" have been asked previously.
Keelan had chimed in about this too [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9969/differences-with-ee).

Comment: Currently I dont think our site has HAMs, we only have a few, most RF questions are not answered.

Comment: I don't think most hams are qualified to answer RF questions beyond the most basic. Even if the proposal were accepted, I'd probably continue ask my RF questions here.

Comment: HAMs are as diverse a group as any; some have some impressive advanced knowledge, others are newbies in electronics. That said, I don't think the EE.SE site should entertain *all* HAM related questions. Many would be off topic if they pertained to spectrum usage, FCC regulations, or non-**design** questions about signal strength, antenna orientation, atmospheric effects on HF...  I'm not saying HAM interests don't belong here, but there's a lot that isn't strictly EE *design*. (Yes, I am a HAM.)

Comment: @JYelton You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Matt Point taken, done.

Comment: @PhilFrost I should rephrase, we dont have the support structure to handle RF questions, with RF experts we would get a whole range below that could be answered and supported. I dont think we handle RF questions well.

Comment: @Kortuk: I haven't specifically looked, but hadn't formed the impression that RF questions are generally not answered here.  Do you have some real data to back up that assertion?

Comment: @OlinLathrop No data, and not that they are off topic, just not well supported from what I have seen. I have multiple friends who are ham and a separate community makes sense to me.

Comment: @Kortuk: If we really aren't doing a good job serving the RF side of EE, then we should consider how to fix that, not shed it. Unlike the separate arduino site where my attitude was *good riddance*, hams are generally more interested in the technology and it would be good to expand our RF questions and answers here. Besides, a lot of ham electronics isn't RF-specific. While there are parts of ham that would be off topic here, I don't see draining the RF part of EE over to a ham site as a good thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not all ham topics would be a fit for EE.SE, most would be.  Spectrum usage, FCC regulations, issues of maximizing signal strength, antenna design and orientation, and atmospheric effects on RF are all either directly EE questions or in the problem set of what a professional EE could deal with in a RF project.

Hams often have a great deal of practical get-it-done knowledge, and it would be good to attract more of them to this site.  Anyone that has gone thru the trouble to get a ham license has passed a significant moron filter, so unlike arduinies, hams on the whole would be a beneficial addition to this site.

There are some ham-related issues that would be off topic here, like which receiver or transmitter is better, what various models cost, where to get them, etc.  This isn't a ham site, but can serve the electronics side of ham radio well.

No, I'm not a ham.

Answer (score 10):

HAMs are as diverse a group as any; some have some impressive advanced knowledge, others are newbies in electronics. That said, I don't think the EE.SE site should entertain all HAM related questions. Many would be off topic if they pertained to spectrum usage, FCC regulations, or non-design questions about signal strength, antenna orientation, atmospheric effects on HF... I'm not saying HAM interests don't belong here, but there's a lot that isn't strictly EE design.

<sub>*(Yes, I am a HAM.)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Ham or not to ham is the wrong way to ask, IMO - clearly the answers so far reflect that. I think the content of a ham's message should be judged on the merits of the contents of his or her post - just like any other poster's would be.

RF questions are clearly on topic - consider you can't design anything with a processor running over, what is it now, 100MHz, without FCC considerations (in the US, of course).

On the other hand, if a ham posts about cool radio designs he saw at the XYZ ham fest, that'd be a good candidate for off-topic flagging.

Not a ham, was a ham, not a ham, might be again